# Sort by newest date using php

Tags: php

```
I have the following date field, I need to sort by newest date.
```

Please help me to solve this.
 tried the following query but it's not getting the correct output.

```
17/12/2014
26/01/2016
19/11/2014
30/06/2014
```

I need to sort in the following format :

```
26/01/2016
17/12/2014
19/11/2014
30/06/2014
```

Here is my code.

```
 $queryold="SELECT * FROM tablename order by  STR_TO_DATE(column name,'%m/%d/%Y')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is not working because you have dd/mm/yyyy format. so you need first date then month in conversation

```
$queryold="SELECT * FROM tablename order by  STR_TO_DATE(column_name,'%d/%m/%Y')";
```

Answer (score 2):

If your column's type is 'datetime' you just have to run this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY datecolumn DESC";
```

If it's a varchar the good query is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, datecolumn) DESC";
```

Comment: my column type is varchar.How to sort it?